# How to delete images related to model object - Django

Tags: django

I have two Models seen below, and three ModelForms (add/edit, delete, image)
On the 'add vegetable' page, the model forms for these two models allow a person to add a new vegetable and add pictures to it. I also have an edit and a delete vegetable page:

On my delete vegetable page, I want the related images to be deleted from the filesystem when a vegetable object is deleted, I have read about post_delete but I not sure how to implement this in my views.

On the edit page I want to be able to see and delete images individually. My edit page is prepopulated with the model instance, but I am not sure how to display the images related to the model and make them editable.

How do I achieve this?
I am not sure if I have to do this in my models or if it should be done in my views...

```
class Vegetable
    ...

Class VegetableImage(models.Model):
    vegetable = models.ForeignKey(Vegetable, default=None, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would override the delete method on the Vegetable class.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete

Here, find all related VegetableImage objects (self.images) and delete them

Good luck